# Flex TabbedViewNavigatorApplication question about sending data

Tags: view, navigation, flex4.5

I have a TabbedViewNavigatorApplication with 3 views(ViewNavigator), 
I can use the navigator.pushView(view,dataobject) from actionscript to navigate to another view with a data object of my choice.
How do I pass a data object of my choice when the user clicks on the default tab button along the bottom to switch views?

Answer (score 1):

Look into firstData... That will allow you to associate a data object with each tab in the TabbedViewNavigatorApplication.

Comment: This might be an answer if you gave specifics.